# How to convert geometry type to latitude x longitude in Ruby

Tags: ruby, coordinates

The `PostgresSQL` DBMS has the `ST_TRANFORM` method to convert a coordinate stored like a hash (geometry column type) in latitude and longitude, how to implement that in `Ruby`, or it exists a lib developed for that feature?

Answer (score 1):

Hashed coordinates usually called *GeoHash* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

This is GeoHash converter for ruby https://github.com/davetroy/geohash
You can decode some geohash like this:

```
GeoHash.decode('f77')
=> [63.98438, -73.82813]
```

Comment: I tried to install the gem, but an error was raised. I install the 
```geohash_ruby``` and this works, but still I have a doubt: the genereted hash by postgres It's like this: ```0101000020E6100000AAAFC1D5149D45C0BF60376C5BE436C0```,but the tested gem raise error because the size of this hash.

Comment: Can you provide sql definition of your column?

Comment: Yes, sure. Sorry for the delay. The column type is ```geometry```. I installed the gem ```activerecord-postgis-adapter``` and it recognize the geometry type and put a ```RGeo::Cartesian::PointImpl```object in attributes that contain the geometry type. But, because don't know the implementation of ```RGeo::Cartesian::PointImpl```, i don't know found a record by attribute of geometry type, for example, but i need that.